# Finite Number of Periodic Points in the Julia Set

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

I'm working through Sullivan's proof to his no wandering theorem, and in one of his sections he claims that the set of points of lowest period in the Julia set is finite. I am struggling to see why this is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The set of points of any particular period, say $n$, of the function $f$ are the roots of a polynomial, namely $f^n(z)-z$.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you